# Generalising airline overbooking fines

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, combinations

[Related:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203271/binomial-distribution-problem-airline-overbooking) but i'm more interested in the fines - the linked question has some graphs that follow what you vaguely expect to happen.

I am working with spreadsheets so I can see lots of values at once, but the problem is still the same: how to calculate the expected fine for a given flight?

My main issue is that I do not know how to calculate the values to use for multiple being "bumped off" flights. If for example we have 180 seats on the plane and 181 seats sold, a 90% chance that a passenger turns up, then it is straightforward to calculate the probability and multiply that by the given fine.

However, if 182 seats are sold, then it is more tricky, as there are two probabilities - one passenger bumped off or two. How do I generalize the equation for the probability that M people get bumped off and then multiply that to get the general equation for the fine paid?

Comment: It is impossible unless you have some model of how people travel. I suppose people don't always order tickets one and one but maybe as groups, families et.c. Then which passengers will bump off won't be independent.

Comment: @mathreadler I did model it, and as stated in the question I am assuming there is a 90% chance that a passenger turns up and that it is independent of other passengers turning up

Comment: Okay. I think it is not a very realistic model, but maybe a good start. In many cases I think if $n$ people book tickets together and $1$ hop off, then larger portions of the group than just $1$ would end up hopping off.

Comment: @mathreadler  probably but at my level I don't want to model that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that there are $n$ seats on the plane and $n+m$ tickets sold, that the probability of a passenger showing up is $p$ and that the fine per bummed passenger equals $f$. Since we are dealing with a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), the probability of having $k$ passengers show up equals:

$${n+m \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n+m-k}$$

As such, the expected fine to be paid equals:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} {n+m \choose n+i} p^{n+i} (1-p)^{m-i} if$$

In practice, tickets can be added to a flight as long as the additional revenue makes up for the increased expected fine to be paid.